Sharpen Unity game in post processing
I am making a game that uses a custom voxel raytracing shader which preferably should run on lower end pcs. Since raytracing performance is extremely affected by resolution I would like to add a setting for 75% resolution but that makes it extremely blurry most of the time.
Because of my simple geometry and the fact that I don't use textures sharpening edges in such an image seems very easy - is there a way to do this in Unity?

At a simple level you can create a RenderTexture with your desired target resolution, render your voxels to that, then render that texture through another camera at full screen resolution, with a shader that applies whatever upsampling/antialiasing/sharpening filter you want. Do you need help setting up that two-stage render, or with writing the upsampling shader? Have you done research into upsampling algorithms to identify the one(s) you want to implement?
